# Step size and stability of Euler forward method

Tags: stability, explicit-methods

I'm trying to calculate the maximum step size that provides stability for the following nonlinear IVP using the Euler forward method:

$u'(t) = -200tu(t)^2,\qquad u_0 = 1, \qquad t\in [0,3]$,

with the analytical solution being $u = (1+100t^2)^{-1}$ (see figure below).[image] From linear stability analysis, that is by solving $u' = \lambda u, \qquad u_0 = 1, \qquad \lambda <0 $, one can show that the region of stability for the Euler forward is $|1+\lambda h|\le1$, where $h$ is the step size. So the step size must be $h<2/|\lambda|$. 
I realize that this holds only for linear problems, however when solving a general IVP (including nonlinear terms):

$u'(t) = f(t,u(t)), \qquad u(t_0)=u_0$

calculating the eigenvalues $\lambda_i(t)$ of $A=f_{u_i}(t,u(t))$, where $f_{u_i}$ is the Jacobian matrix, should also lead to reasonable step sizes when using the lowest value of all $\lambda_i$. That is if the $u(t)$ is asymptotically stable. 
So the next step would be to calculate the Jacobian matrix (in this case with just one entry): 
$f_{u_i}=-\frac{400t}{1+100t^2}=\lambda$. The infimum of $\lambda$ on the given interval is $\lambda=-20$ and thus  $h = 2/20$. The figure below shows $\lambda(t)$.
 [image]
 However the step size seems to be too large as the model blows up. Stability seems to be somewhere around $h=2/29$. 
So I have two Questions: 
1: What did I do wrong while calculating the step size or is the example just pathological and if so why? 
2: How can I actually calculate the maximum step size providing stability?

Comment: Keep in mind there is no guarantee of stability for forward Euler method. As a result, the step-size that you calculated based on your stability analysis is just an approximation and for nonlinear ODEs it might be really terrible approximation. In fact, foward Euler method has only **conditional** stability even for linear ODEs and you should not expect to estimate step-size precisely even for linear ODEs.

Comment: Just to make sure, we're on same page: by conditional stability you mean, that it is not sufficient for the stability of Euler forward that $\lambda <0$, but it also needs to be within the region of stability (since forward Euler is not A-stable)?

Comment: Yes, it means for plenty of cases if you continue integrating long enough, finally you will see instability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the exact solution to estimate $\lambda$ may not give a time step that works for the numerical scheme. The local estimate of $\lambda$ is
$$
\lambda = 400 t u
$$
If you try this step
$$
h = \min(2/20, 2/(400 t u+10^{-12}))
$$
it is stable, but of course accuracy is poor. Here is a code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = 0.0
u = 1.0
tdata, udata = [], []
tdata.append(t); udata.append(u)
while t<3.0:
    dt = np.min([2.0/20.0, 2.0/(400*t*u+1.0e-12)])
    rhs = - 200.0*t*u**2
    u = u + dt*rhs
    t += dt
    print("dt, t =", dt, t)
    tdata.append(t); udata.append(u)

tdata = np.array(tdata); udata = np.array(udata)
uexact = 1.0/(1.0 + 100*tdata**2)
plt.plot(tdata,udata,tdata,uexact)
plt.legend(('Forward Euler','Exact'))
plt.xlabel('t'); plt.ylabel('u')
plt.show()
```

In first step, step size is $h=0.1$. After first step, the numerical solution is still $u=1$ and 
$$
\lambda = 400*0.1*1 = 40
$$
so you need to use step size
$$
h \le 2/40 = 0.05
$$
in second step, which is less than $2/20=0.1$.

There is another issue with this particular problem. Starting at $u=1$, the solution should remain in $[0,1]$. If it becomes negative for some reason, then forward euler will take it to $-\infty$, as happens for $h=2/20$. The ODE itself has this behaviour. So for this problem, if exact solution is supposed to be positive, time step should be chosen so that numerical solution remains positive.
$$
u_{n+1} = u_n - 200 t_n u_n^2 h
$$
We have $u_n \ge 0$ $\implies$ $u_{n+1} \ge 0$ iff
$$
h \le \frac{1}{200 t_n u_n}
$$
and this condition also agrees with the restriction from linear stability analysis.

Comment: So my mistake was to look at the analytical derivative instead of looking at the numerical one. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer.